# Object detection from image using vision framework

Tags: objective-c, ios11, object-detection, coreml, apple-vision

I am trying to detect objects from a given image. From research I just found that we can detect and track an object for the videos using the following process:

```
private lazy var cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)

private func tapGestureAction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) 
 {
   highlightView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
   highlightView.center = recognizer.location(in: view)

   let originalRect = highlightView.frame
   var convertedRect = cameraLayer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: originalRect)
   convertedRect.origin.y = 1 - convertedRect.origin.y

   previousObservation = VNDetectedObjectObservation(boundingBox: convertedRect)
 }
```

Can we have similar method like `metadataOutputRectConverted` for imageView? I am trying to detect the object rect whenever the user taps on that object. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

this method to convert the camera output rect ( topleft(0,0) to bottomright(0,1)) to the UI rect. So, I think you do not need to convert it

Comment: elaborate your answer, add some code to demonstrate it.